# Recipients.ResolveAll half failing

Tags: c#, outlook, contacts

My goal is to add/remove recipients to an existing `MailItem mailItem`.

I add the newEmailAdress ("some.one@corp.com"):

```
mailItem.To += "some.one@corp.com";
```

I then resolve the recipients so it looks nicer for the user (like having the Skype status displaying for internal contacts).

```
mailItem.Recipients.ResolveAll();
```

It works for half of them. For some, if I look into the `mailItem.To`, the email string has been changed to the contact name ("Some One") and the contact is not in the `mailItem.Recipients`. BUT they show as resolved (they have the Skype status for instance, or have (contact) for external ones).
So it's somehow half resolved, for half of the recipients. I couldn't find any logic, some internal contacts work, others don't, same for external recipients...

Google is of not much help. I will deactivate the ResolveAll for the moment so my tool can continue working, but pointers would be appreciated!

**For context:**
To add/remove recipients,

- I handle emails added directly to `mailItem.To` checking with a simple `mailItem.To.Contains(newEmailAdress)` to avoid duplicates, and deleting with `mailItem.Replace(newEmailAdress, "")`. Works fine.
- I then want to handle contacts that have already been resolved or entered directly as Recipients. I go through the `mailItem.Recipients`, convert the email adress using a `PropertyAcessor`, and then it's only about comparing with the `newMailAdress`. That's how I noticed some were half resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To / CC / BCC property may or may not contain email addresses - you should assume they only contain names.

Also, multiple names must be separated with ";":

```
mailItem.To += ";some.one@corp.com";
```

That being said, use `MailItem.Recipients` collection and especially the `Recipients.Add` method. You can iterate through all items in that collection and for each recipient, examine the `Recipient.`Name and `Recipient.Ad`dress properties.

Comment: I will try with `Recipients.Add` . At least that way I'll be sure that they are in the Recipients collection.   However, this doesn't explain ithe behaviour I noted, as I'm myself adding full emails to the To/CC properties, correctly separated by ";".

Comment: It did work as expected managing both additions and deletions with Recipients.Add() and Recipient.Delete(). It doesn't exactly explain the issue I had, BUT it does solve my problem! So thanks!